# Building React Native source for Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, react-native

I'm trying to build React Native locally.  I followed the Facebook instructions from [Building React Native from source](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html#building-react-native-from-source)
but when I do the command **react-native run-android**, I receive the following error:

> :ReactAndroid:downloadBoost
> Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: sf_mirror_attempt="boost:iweb:boost/1.57.0/boost_1_57_0.zip"; expires=120; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: 120
>
> :ReactAndroid:downloadBoost FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':ReactAndroid:downloadBoost'.
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Any ideas as to what I may have done wrong?

Comment: it looks like u r trying to access an https site that either has an invalid certificate or u dont have ur ssl store reference correctly in your app.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that your computer is not able to download boost_1_57_0.zip file with the https path that is in your settings (invalid certificate).

Go to your project's *project_root/node_modules/react-native/ReactAndroid/build.gradle* file and change the **src** attribute on the **task downloadBoost** part to any proxy that you find to boost_1_57_0.zip and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error and the error went away after using the correct Android NDK (currently android-ndk-r10e). But if you've followed the instructions, as you've said, then that is most likely not your problem.